# How we call onPause Method through RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android

How we call onpause Method through recyclerView Adapter

please help me how  can solve this

Answer (score -1):

Here I'll take an example of a stopwatch where we can focus on focus changing, configuration changing (to portrait to landscape) and onPause() and onResume() method...
you must know that it's the same way as onStart() and onStop() method, here you have the code:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // Get a reference for the stopwatch
        stopwatch = findViewById(R.id.stopwatch)
        // Restore the previous state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            offset = savedInstanceState.getLong(OFFSET_KEY)
            running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(RUNNING_KEY)
            if (running) {
                stopwatch.base = savedInstanceState.getLong(BASE_KEY)
                stopwatch.start()
            }else setBaseTime()
        }
        // what the app does when another activity makes it invisible.
        fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
            if (running) {
                saveOffset()
                stopwatch.stop()
            }
        }

        fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            if (running) {
                setBaseTime()
                stopwatch.start()
                offset = 0
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).